# Deleted The Catalog Price Rule Accidently In Magento Without Inactive

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am new to Magento. I have created The Rule Of 10 % discount for three categories I mistakenly deleted the rule instead of inactivity of the rule. Then I made another of 10% discount and applied to the same category I see that there is 20 % discount. So the first rule which I have deleted still persist on the products. Kindly show me the path if possible.

Comment: Perform indexing and apply discount and clear cache

Comment: hello pankaj sir i have already done That ! but it is not solving my problem

Comment: delete your all rule .. then perform indexing .. and when original price show then create rule and apply

Comment: i havd done as you said that i have firstly deleted the rule and then re indexed the data but its is not working i think there is entry in the database !!

Comment: If you are working on local server and there is only one catalog rule .. the try to truncate folloing tables: catalogrule
 catalogrule_affected_product
 catalogrule_customer_group
 catalogrule_group_website
 catalogrule_product
 catalogrule_product_price
 catalogrule_website

Comment: Hi Pankaj Pareek Sir i Have truncated The Following Table I Have Now Only One Problem ! the price on The Frontend Shows 15 % discount but wen i click on the page on the description page it shows proper 12 % discount what should i do for that please help !

Answer (score 1):

Burhan, The issue stems from how Magento applies rules, when a rule is applied these rules discounts are indexed and if your existing rule was mistakenly deleted it will still be active until you click "apply rules" from the rule dashboard.

In the top right hand corner you see a button called "Apply Rules" click that and then rebuild indexes. The Save and Apply within a rule will not reset past rules.

Try this and let me know what happens.

[image]

Comment: Thank  you Rob sir I First I Applied rule And Then I reindexed The Data But It is Not solving the Problem ! please show me Some Path If Possible Thanks Sir !

Comment: Sir thank you very much problem is resolved thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem where i deleted the catalogue rule before making it inactive..

Got around to fixing it by running the following MySQL commands

1. `update catalogrule_product set action_amount = "0.0000" where rule_id="xx"`  where xx = your own rule id from the DB
2. Re-index the price file
3. Refresh Cache

Prices should now be restored to original value